# Can you tell if a data extension doesn't exist when using DataExtension.Init?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I'm adding error handling to a CloudPage to alert if the script is trying to look up values from a DE that doesn't exist. However when using DataExtension.Init on a DE that doesn't exist it appears to generate an object anyway, making error handling difficult. Is there a way to know if the DE called by the function doesn't exist?

The below code prints the result "configDE.length  = 3"

````
  Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
  var configDE = DataExtension.Init("this does not exist");
  Write("configDE.length  = " + configDE.length);
</script>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not necessarily have to initialize the DE at all, if you lookup via Platform functions. so you could do this before calling the Init() function.

Init() is only relevant for Core functions, which is implicitly documented by *where* this is mentioned in the docs:

Server-Side JavaScript - server-Side JavaScript Syntax Guide - **Core Library Functions** - Data Extension Functions

Source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_coreLibraryFunctions.htm

```
To interact with a data extension via server-side JavaScript, you must first initialize the object. This code initializes a data extension with the external key of birthdayDE.

var birthdayDE = DataExtension.Init("birthdayDE");
```

===

Without the need to do this, a cheap workaround is to add a field that has a default value to all records in said DE.

fieldname: include

default value: 1

With that, you could just try a simple lookup and process the results:

```
var myDEName = "myDE"


var dataRows = Platform.Function.LookupRows(myDEName,'include','1');
if(dataRows && dataRows.length > 0) {
   /* success */
} else { 
   /* error handling */
}
```

Source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformDataExtensionLookupRows.htm

Comment: Thanks Jonas - that's very helpful. Rather than adding an additional field, I will use an existing field and use a filter to lookup using the Rows.Retrieve method.
`<script runat="server">
  Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
  var configDE = DataExtension.Init("non-existant DE name");
  var data = configDE.Rows.Retrieve({Property:"Field",SimpleOperator:"greaterThan",Value:0});
  if (data == 0)
  {
    //error handling
  }
</script>`

Comment: yes that is a better option if it can be ensured that the value will always be found. in many cases that is not the case, then the additional fields comes in very handy, I've actually used it a lot myself.